# Proper syntax for complex equation in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to translate this equation into excel.

[image: equation]

My closest attempt was

```
=1200*(1.12)^4 -1/ 0.12*(1.12)^4/(1.12)^4,
```

but instead I got 1879.89.
What the proper syntax for this equation in excel (no functions).

Comment: =1200*(1.12^4 -1)/( 0.12*1.12^4)/1.12^4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to get the `()` in the correct spots:

```
=(1200*((1.12^4 -1)/ (0.12*1.12^4)))/1.12^4
```

[image]

Comment: Okay that works, but how about something a bit more complex like =C7*(1+B2)^(E2-3)-1/B2*(1+B2)^(E2-3)/B2*(1+B2)^3, C7 is 6224400, E2 is 40 and B2 is 0.025. The answer should be 138472680.

Comment: Pay attention to the `()` and make them match mine.

Comment: Yes that worked thank you.